# Preventing a 'heartbeat timeout' with websockets and SocketIO

Tags: websocket, socket.io, connection-timeout

I am using NodeJS and SocketIO for my websocket solution. It works fine, but after a few minutes, my socket server always times out with the following messages in my console:

```
debug - fired heartbeat timeout for client
info - transport end <heartbeat timeout>
debug - set close timeout for client
debug - cleared close timeout for client
debug - discarding transport
```

Here is my complete `server.js` file:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(3000);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'from socket server' });

  socket.on('swipe', function (from, msg) {
     console.log('I received a private message by ', from, ' saying ', msg);
     socket.emit('swipe event received on server!');
  });
```

How can I prevent the timeouts from happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the **close timeout** and **heartbeat timeout** options [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO)

You can set these programmatically on the server via:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);
io.set('close timeout', 60);
io.set('heartbeat timeout', 60);
```

As for the design of your application, you should check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914768/is-it-safe-to-set-a-high-close-timeout-on-socket-io) question for whether or not you should change the timeout.