# Socket.io 1.0 : configure close timeout

Tags: node.js, sockets, io, socket.io

How can I configure the option 'close timeout' with the code below ?

```
 var app = require('express')();
 var server = require('http').Server(app);
 var io = require('socket.io')(server);
 ...
 server.listen(port, ip);
```

I read the doc about socket.io and I found that :

```
 var socket = require('socket.io')({
     // options go here
 });
```

but I can't add options because I'm using the `server` variable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20387975/1694735) ?

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);
io.set('close timeout', 60);
io.set('heartbeat timeout', 60);
```

Maybe something like

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.set('close timeout', 60);
server.listen(port, ip);
```

**Edit:** This is a long shot but:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
server['close timeout'] = 60;
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(port, ip);
```

**Edit:**
Found this on [socket.io docs](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/):

```
// pass a server and the `serveClient` option
var io = require('socket.io')(http, { serveClient: false });
```

So, what about this?

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server, { 'close timeout': 60});
server.listen(port, ip);
```

**Yet another Edit:**
In [docs](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/) again:

> The same options passed to socket.io are always passed to
>   the engine.io Server that gets created. See [engine.io options](https://github.com/Automattic/engine.io#methods-1) as reference.

```
pingTimeout (Number): how many ms without a pong packet to consider the connection closed (60000)
```

Can you try this?

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server, { pingTimeout: 60000});
server.listen(port, ip);
```

Comment: io.set() is deprecated since socket.io 1.0, I can't use this

Comment: 'server['close timeout'] = 60;' is not a bad idea but it doesn't work. I'm wondering if I do things correctly -_-'

Comment: I already tried 'var io = require('socket.io')(server, { 'close timeout': 60});' => didn't work :( it's weird and that is why I'm wondering if I do something wrong ...

Comment: I'm no socket.io expert but I went and checked [it's source](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/master/lib/index.js) and I can't find 'close timeout'. If this option was supressed in the new version there should be a better way to achieve what you are trying to do...

Comment: I'm just trying to reduce the time between disconnection (by closing page for example) and when the disconnect event is fired. Locally, it's instant but on a remote server, this time is fixed by default to 60 seconds (too much ...). And the 'close timeout' option was the better (only ?) option I found.

Comment: I found something else. Check my last edit. (I'm not really sure if it works. I'm just going through the docs)

Comment: And maybe consider playing with pingInterval too

Comment: Thanks for your help :) using just pingTimeout doesn't work. I'll try adding pingInterval later. I'll tell you if it's ok

Comment: So, after reading that, pingTimeout is an option for engine.io but I use socket.io. I found same option, according 'var io = require('socket.io')(server);' => 'io.engine.pingTimeout' and 'io.engine.pingInterval' but still doesn't work ...

Comment: @user3146857 - `socket.io` is built on top of `engine.io`.  `engine.io` is the transport.

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest version. `{ pingTimeout: 60000}` works fine for me.

And `io.set('heartbeat timeout', 10)` works as well, but `set` will be removed in the future.